# A JS function containing an array of lots of special characters isn't working

Tags: javascript, console

I'm new at coding, i started learning JS in Codecademy...there's a project in this course called "Password Validator"...according to this project, i made this function named `hasSpecialCharacter` to check if the password has at least one special character but when i completed this code and tried to run this using a sample password, it does nothing and the console stops working...

I tried to run that code in my PC from VS Code and Powershell as JS console but when I run this, the console shows nothing but the task keeps running...I even tried removing some characters from the array but it still didn't work...

```js
function hasUpperCase(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
  
function hasLowerCase(input) {
    for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (input[j] === input[j].toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
  
function isLongEnough(input) {
    if (input.length >= 8) {
        return true;
    }
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input) {
    var specialCharacters = ['`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '{', '}', ';', ':', '\'', '"', '\\', '|', ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?'];
    
    for (var k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
        for (var l = 0; specialCharacters.length; l++) {
            if (input[k] === specialCharacters[l]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function isPasswordValid(input) {
    if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) && isLongEnough(input)) {// && hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
        console.log("The password is valid");
    } if (!hasUpperCase(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast 1 capital letter");
    } if (!hasLowerCase(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast one small letter");
    } if (!isLongEnough(input)) {
        console.log("The password must be atleast 8 characters long");
    } if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast 1 special character");
    }
}
  
isPasswordValid('red');
```

I thought the output in the console would be this:

```
PS C:\Users\Fuad Hasan\Desktop\Codes> node .\passwordValidator2.js
The password needs atleast 1 capital letter
The password must be atleast 8 characters long
The password needs atleast 1 special character
```

but the console cursor just keeps blinking like sth is loading after this:

```
PS C:\Users\Fuad Hasan\Desktop\Codes> node .\passwordValidator2.js
The password needs atleast 1 capital letter
The password must be atleast 8 characters long
...
```

Comment: The code causes an infinite loop on this line for (var l = 0; specialCharacters.length; l++) replace it with for (var l = 0; l < specialCharacters.length; l++)

Comment: Let me explain why the code causes an infinite loop. The second part of a for loop is a conditional. This is where the for loop decides when to stop executing. Since specialCharacters.length is defined the condition always evaluates to true and the loop never exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code.

Edit this line

> `for (var l = 0; specialCharacters.length; l++) {`

to

> `for (var l = 0; l < specialCharacters.length; l++) {`

Execute/run the snippet below:

```js
function hasUpperCase(input) {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
  
function hasLowerCase(input) {
    for (var j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (input[j] === input[j].toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
  
function isLongEnough(input) {
    if (input.length >= 8) {
        return true;
    }
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input) {
    var specialCharacters = ['`', '~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '+', '=', '{', '}', ';', ':', '\'', '"', '\\', '|', ',', '<', '.', '>', '/', '?'];
    
    for (var k = 0; k < input.length; k++) {
        for (var l = 0; l < specialCharacters.length; l++) {
            if (input[k] === specialCharacters[l]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

function isPasswordValid(input) {
    if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) && isLongEnough(input)) {// && hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
        console.log("The password is valid");
    } if (!hasUpperCase(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast 1 capital letter");
    } if (!hasLowerCase(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast one small letter");
    } if (!isLongEnough(input)) {
        console.log("The password must be atleast 8 characters long");
    } if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)) {
        console.log("The password needs atleast 1 special character");
    }
}
  
console.log('Validating password: "red"');
isPasswordValid('red');
console.log('Validating password: "red@Redcolor"');
isPasswordValid('red@Redcolor');
```